# No Static Content on Category Pages in Magento 2.1

Tags: static-block, magento-2.1

I am using Magento 2.1 CE in production mode. When going to a category in the backend and either adding a description and/or a static block then saving it, the changes are not seen on the front end. It does not work for any category that I have tried.

When adding a static block I changed the display setting from products only to display static block and products. This did not make a difference.

Is anyone else experiencing this issue?

**Edit:** Running the indexers:reindex command twice from the CLI after making a change in the backend to the content of a category makes the changes visible on the front end. It appears reindexing is not working as it should automatically. Cron jobs are setup and running without errors.

**Edit 2:** I am seeing some lines show up in the debug.log file after trying to update a category and it not working. The actual store URL has been replaced with "STORE URL" in the block below.

```
[2016-07-25 12:17:34] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"STORE URL","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["catalog_category_21","catalog_category","catalog_category_product_21"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2016-07-25 12:17:34] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"STORE URL","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["catalog_category_21","FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2016-07-25 12:17:34] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"STORE URL","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["catalog_category","FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2016-07-25 12:17:34] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"STORE URL","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["catalog_category_product_21","FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
```

I setup an additional cron job to reindex every minute with the other cron jobs and that seems to work. For some reason the indexes are not being reindexed by the regular cron jobs though.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/magento2/bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: You should flush cache magento and reload browser again. If not work try to reindex

Comment: I did flush the cache and that did not seem to make a difference. I manually went and issued the reindex command and it still didn't appear. The static block appeared a while after that. I then removed the static block/content and it took a long time again to disappear. I'm guessing it should update quite a bit faster than this.

Comment: Running the indexers:reindex command twice shows the newly updated content on the front end. This has to be a problem somewhere with Magento.